# Lua Anonymous function storing in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I'm writing a Lua library in C++ that uses callbacks for certain functionalities. For testing I have 2 Lua functions, Register and Call. They are implemented in C++ like this:

```
int Lua_Register(lua_State* l){
    int n = lua_gettop(l);
    if(n==1){
        if(lua_isfunction(l, -1)){
            printf("Register\n")
            lua_pushvalue(l, -1);
            r = luaL_ref(l, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int Lua_Call(lua_State* l){
    lua_rawseti(l, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, r);
    lua_call(l, 0, 0);
    return 1;
}
```

and then in Lua:

```
Register(function()
    Log("hi!")
end)

Call()
```

But all I see in the console is a lot of lines containing `Register`, followed by the message: `C stack overflow`. What I assume the problem is, is that I'm storing `Register`, rather than the anonymous function in the argument, which would create an infinite loop. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you setting a value in the registry in your `Lua_Call` function? Don't you want to get *getting* the value from that index out of the registry at that point so that you can call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, You're trying to overwrite Lua registry with non-existant value instead of executing already set value.

**What are You doing in short:**

```
--calling Register()
lua_pushvalue(l, -1); -- now 2 copies of closure on top of stack
r = luaL_ref(l, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); --one consumed, put into registry, 1 left

--calling Call()
--this C API call has got a new piece of stack
--   which does not contain that leftover of closure copy!
lua_rawseti(l, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, r); --overwrite Lua registry entry with what?
lua_call(l, 0, 0); --What the heck are we calling now?
```

Thanks [siffijoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3677376/siffiejoe) and [Etab Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) for clarification about that new piece of stack.

**What You should be doing:**

I still don't really understand what actually are You trying to do, but in Your Lua code sample to execute properly (closure gets called by `Call()`, You should **retrieve** the closure before executing instead of **overwriting** with something which does not exist on top of the Lua stack. Something like this:

```
int Lua_Call(lua_State* l){
    lua_rawgeti(l, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, r); // <--- retrieve closure from registry!
    lua_call(l, 0, 0); // <--- consider using lua_pcall()
    return 0; // <--- the call does not leave anything useful on the stack.
}
```

**NOTE:** decide, which C API functions of Yours returns something, which ones does not. And change the return value to proper one.

Reference: [luaL_ref()](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_ref), [lua_rawgeti()](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_rawgeti), [lua_pcall()](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pcall) and misused [lua_rawseti()](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_rawseti).

Comment: Between C<->lua transitions lua cleans the stack for you. So there should be nothing on the stack when `Call` is called (as it is called with no arguments).

Comment: Lua gives you a clean slice of the stack for each call, but the Lua stack is still one big [C array](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstate.c.html#stack_init), and [this](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lapi.h.html#api_checknelems) suggests that the called function is in this C array immediately before the current stack slice. That is probably also the reason for the C stack overflow: `Lua_Call` gets called by itself over and over again. (Compiling Lua with API checks enabled should detect this error, btw.)

Comment: @EtanReisner, original question contain C API function sample which returned non-zero value. 1, to be precise. As I remember, returned number "tells" Lua VM how many values were returned to the stack and  weren't cleaned. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Kamiccolo Yes, the number returned from C is the number of arguments the function put on the stack and that lua should take off the stack. If you underflow the stack you cause problems. (This was the API checks comment that siffijoe was making.) My point was that you don't get the same stack between calls to C functions you get a new one each time. So old things pushed on the stack no longer exist the second time.

Comment: @EtanReisner Reisner, thanks for clarification. I think I was mistaken by using nested C API functions. Going to fix my code sample.

Comment: @Kamiccolo Right, as long as you stay on the C side of things you do need to manage your stack correctly between C functions. But the stack is reset every time you enter C from lua.